# Prepending text before a node in a child

Tags: javascript, prepend

I am currently making a userscript that prepends a newly created element to the end of a child of another element. I have successfully done this by the following:

```
var link=document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute('href', 'http://orteil.dashnet.org/experiments/cookie/');
link.target = 'blank';
link.appendChild(
document.createTextNode('Cookie Clicker Classic')
);
var add = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[1];
if(add.lastChild) add.insertBefore(link,add.lastChild); 
else add.prependChild(link);
```

My issue now is that there needs to be a separator between the last pre-existing node of the child and the newly created node. I plan to do this by adding a " | " inbetween them. The thing is, I don't know how to... I have tried something like:

> var pipe = document.createElement(' ')
>
> pipe.prependChild(
> document.createTextNode(' | ')
> );

but I have no idea what the "element" type would be, as it is just text, not an "a" tag or a "p" tag... so I can't go "var pipe = document.createElement('a')" from my understanding.

I would appreciate if anyone could atleast give hints if not a solution.
Thanks in advance,
Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track with `createTextNode`. Just:

```
if(add.lastChild) add.insertBefore(link,add.lastChild); 
else add.prependChild(link);
add.insertBefore(document.createTextNode('|'), link);
```

But I **think** your code could be simpler:

```
add.insertBefore(document.createTextNode('|'), add.lastChild);
add.insertBefore(link,add.lastChild);
```

I'm not sure why you're calling `prependChild` when `add` is empty, and note that it's perfectly fine to call `insertBefore` with `null` as the second argument (it just appends).